# Using decimal-format crashes my app on samsung S3

Tags: android, crash, decimalformat

When I use Decimal-format in my app in a certain activity,it crashes when reaching that activity only on Samsung S3 but it works great on all other phones.

```
  x=Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(x));
```

When I remove this line,the app works great on S3 but surely too much numbers after the dot.
any help please??
Thanks.

Comment: I think the s3 is too old for jre7 calls. I'm not sure if there's a builtin alternative. You could convert the number to a string and loop over the characters, counting manually the digits after the decimal; and truncating where needed.

Comment: So its a jre issue.I got your way and I'll try it.THANKS a lot for your answer.